# How to get active Wordpress plugins with version numbers?

Tags: wordpress

I need to find all active plugins used in a site (including network) with their version numbers. I tried using `get_plugins()` but it doesn't tell me if the plugins are active or not. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Activated plugins are stored in the `options` table of WordPress, which means you can use [`get_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option):

```
get_option('active_plugins');
```

A full list of options keys can be viewed in the [Codex's Options Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference).

You can compare this array to the array returned by `get_plugins()` to get your version numbers.